# Spring Boot Tomcat Embed CA SSO / Siteminder Intercept

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, single-sign-on, siteminder

I've got a simple SPA Sprint Boot application - executable jar with embedded tomcat and looking to plug it into siteminder with preauthenticatedauthenticationprovider. Application is `http://someserver:1234`

Documentation states that a WebAgent is installed on a web server and that 'intercepts' requests. Would the WebAgent be deployed in a separate container? If so, how does it intercept requests? All documentation refers to this intercept, but doesn't state the mechanism.

Does it need to be deployed inside the same container to intercept requests? The only way I can think any http headers are intercepted is through proxies.

Comment: There are either too many possible answers, or good answers would be too long for this format. Please add details to narrow the answer set or to isolate an issue that can be answered in a few paragraphs.

Answer (score 1):

There are 2 ways to configure Web Agent.
1. **Local Configuration**
    - Setup Agent in the sever where Applciaiton is hosted.
2. **Centralized Configuration**
    - Setup  Agent in the a web server like Apache and add proxy entries to the backend applications. this configuration intercepts each and every request going from the webagent server. I recommend this. if you have still questions drop here.
    - Thanks,
Chiranjeevi